# 3-step shot in basketball

Tags: basketball, technique

After the last bounce, followed by two further steps, then a shot to hoop before the end of the third step.

Is this action or the whole process called *3-step shot*?[image] In other words, what is the boy doing in the animated picture?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? because after you stop bouncing you can do only two more step, 3rd step will be count as travelling.

Comment: What is the quote from?

Comment: I just want to format the text with a quote. It's removed since it is confusing. @DorCohen, maybe I didn't describe it clearly, what I was trying to say is exactly what the boy is doing in the animated picture.

Comment: It looks like a legit play.

Answer (score 3):

The animation you reference represents an ideal case scenario of a "[lay up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layup)."

This is just one example of a lay up. There are many examples because of defensive factors.