# FIBA rule: 0-1-2 layup footwork?

Tags: basketball, fiba

I have a footwork question about new FIBA rule on the layup.

Regarding the new rule, the step during picking up the ball is called "Step 0", after that one can still use two more steps (at maximum) before shooting / passing.

Say now I am driving to right hand side, normally with a dribble step:  right hand pound the ball to the ground and left foot step forward at the same time. From there, if I pick up the ball and start the layup, the footwork would be like:

*right foot + pick up (step 0) -> left foot (step 1) -> right foot (step 2)*

Ends up a same foot same hand lay up on the right hand side, which is possible but feels weird.

What if I want to end up with a left foot layup (but still using all 0-1-2 steps)? When should I pick up the ball and the how the footwork should be?

Comment: See: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/3-step-shot-in-basketball/2747#2747